# Circular dependencies return undefined

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, dependencies, babeljs

I wanted to refactor my Nodejs/Babel 7 app. It's a GraphQL app with Bookshelf.js models to control a database. So I organized my code into few chunks:

- index.js, server.js and a few other "free" files, that are basically entry points to an app
- directory with models, finished with kind-of index file, that forwards exports (example below)
- directory with GQL types, with similar index file
- directory with GQL queries, again with similar index file
- directory with services, similar index file

So far so good. Before refactor modules just imported certain other modules directly, so a wanted to have nice one-line imports, as such:

```
import {Contact, Product, Set, Content, User} from 'models/Models'
```

But... here is a problem. my modules depend on each other strongly. By that I mean that a model sometimes imports a service or type, service can import models, and so on. When I run the code, I found a bunch of "expected something, but found undefined" errors. I researched the matter and found out that it's because of circular dependencies - my index files are not fully loaded and because of that they return undefined. Funny thing is, before I reorganized the code everything was working (so there is no real problem with circular dependencies, they can be solved by transpiler, but when I use "index" files to structure imports it cannot).

Obvious solution would be to return to previous structure and just live with it, but it's only a short-term solution. How can I solve this problem?

Example of "index" file (trimmed):

```
export { default as Contact } from 'models/ancestor/Contact'
export { default as Content } from 'models/ancestor/Content'

export { default as UserData } from 'models/mega/UserData'

export { default as Action } from 'models/organization/Action'
export { default as Connection } from 'models/organization/Connection'
```

Comment: Yes, I tested that, too, error stayed basically the same. I think about one other possible solution - changing the order of imports in index files. I don't know if it even might work, though.

Comment: But it is working, look at the example: https://codesandbox.io/s/p9yzxn2njq. They are not mutiple defaults - I'm taking default exports from different files, then I name them and "forward" the export along.